# Going strictly RESTful on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm working on a gaming app (mobile front ends, Rails backend) and trying to decide if I should go strictly RESTful. It appears that I'll be creating a lot more controllers if I do so. For example, there are several game actions I need to implement like attack, defend, etc. If I go strictly RESTful, I'll need to create a controller for each game action with only one REST action (update). If I go non-RESTul and creates say a generic battle controller, I can then create methods/actions for attack, defend, etc. Seems like more hassle to go strictly RESTful.

Any insights will be much appreciated.

Comment: First, you have to ask yourself if REST even makes sense for your application. You're talking about "methods" and "actions", whereas REST is more about "resources". The number of resource types does not depend on the number of game actions--you could have a single resource per player, where you post their current state (*e.g.* attacking, defending, *etc.*). Can you expand more on what you're hoping to accomplish by using REST, or is this more of a buzzword thing? Is this a realtime game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attack, defend, etc are all of the same kind of resource: `Action`.

E.g.:

```
PUT actions/attack # to attack
PUT actions/defend # to defend
GET actions        # to get the list of all available actions
```

To implement this as REST, I'd go something like this:

```
class PlayerActionsController ...
   def index
      @actions = PlayerAction.all
      respond_with @actions
   end

   def update
      @action   = PlayerAction.find(params[:id])        
      respond_with @action.perform(params)
   end
end


class GenericAction
   attr_readable :name

   def initialize(name)
     @name = name
   end

   def perform(arguments)
     self.send(name, arguments) if self.class.find(name)
   end

   ACTIONS = []
   ACTIONS_BY_NAME = {}
   class << self
     def add_action(*names)
        names.each do |name|
          action = Action.new(name)
          ACTIONS_BY_NAME[name] = action
          ACTIONS << action
        end
     end

     def index
       ACTIONS.dup
     end      

     def find(name)
       ACTIONS_BY_NAME[name]
     end
   end
def

class PlayerAction < GenericAction
   add_action :attack, :defend

   def attack(params)
      player, target = Player.find(params[:player_id]), Player.find(params[:target_id])
      ...
   end


   def defend(params)
      ...
   end
end
```

This is just to give a rough idea of how it could be done well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense although technically, there isn't a need for the usual Rails REST actions because there isn't an actions model, they are hardcoded. However, each action will result in changes to other models. Essentially I would create an actions controller and if I want to go RESTful, create custom REST actions. However, it seems that I shouldn't use REST in this case and simply create a controller for all the different actions, thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Storing them like this makes things like action security clearance levels trivial to implement, among other things :)

Comment: Thanks, it's a creative solution though it seems simpler to just implement custom REST actions.